# Multiple Google Maps on a single Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Im trying to display multiple Google Maps on a single page. It is a results page that is dynamically generated per locations in the area. Each div has a map class that I want to run the Google Map off of. As of right now I can only get it to process the information for one div.

I understand that I need to somehow pass Google Maps an array. But I am confused as to how to do this given the uses for my implementation.

**HTML**

```
<div class="map" data-address="123 easy st city st zip" data-title="location"></div>
<div class="map" data-address="456 easy st city st zip" data-title="location 2"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.map').each(function() {

    var geoCode = new google.maps.Geocoder(), 
    container = this;

    geoCode.geocode({'address': $(container).data('address')}, function(results, status) {
    var start_options = 0;

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 14,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
             zoomControl: true,
             scaleControl: false,
             scrollwheel: false,
             disableDefaultUI: true,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

         }

         if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android|Blackberry|Windows Phone|Nokia|HTC|webOS)/)) {
                 mapOptions.draggable=false;
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            title: $(this).data('itemTitle')
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);

        function toggleBounce() {
              if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
              } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
              }
        }

        var center;
        function calculateCenter() {
            center = map.getCenter();
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
            calculateCenter();
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
            map.setCenter(center);
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("map")` is incorrect since `map` is a class.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript to select a class cross-browser.

Comment: in every .map loop youre targeting the same id

Comment: Does the user need to pan around these maps? If not you might be better off using a bunch of [static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) instead.

Comment: @Andy, the maps are being used in a  responsive layout. with the user given the ability to pan around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps won't work when using classes to select multiple canvases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192260/google-maps-wont-work-when-using-classes-to-select-multiple-canvases)

Comment: @geocodezip it's not the same problem, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your forEach loop you are using `document.getElementById("map")`.

This is wrong for a couple of reasons, firstly because the map doesnt have an id, it has a class, and secondly because the map will be attached to the same element each time.

What you want to do is attach the map to the *current* map in the loop. In your jQuery loop this will be the `this` variable.

Conveniently (as `this` can often change inside nested functions), the first line of your loop stores `this` in a variable called `container`.

So simply replace `document.getElementById("map")` with `container`, and you should get a different map attached to each instance of the `.map` element.

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

1. assign id attributes to your divs
2. wrap google map code in a function with one parameter >the container
3. call the function

```
function getGoogleMap(container) 
{
    //google code 
    //use the container parameter like so

    geoCode.geocode({'address': $("#" + container).data('address')});
    //or so
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(container), mapOptions);
}
getGoogleMap("map1");
```