# different array for more google map on same page

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google map, delivery from this example: `Click [here](http://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/working-around-8-waypoint-limit-in-google-maps-directions-api/)

I would like to create two maps, with different makers, and different paths on the same page that just does not seem to be able to pass new values ​​to google map for a different canvas-map based on the values ​​passed to the function.

In the my example: Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lombo/qLTsS/) clarifies my problem.

```
<p class="openmap" data-id="map">click here for map<p>
<p class="openmap" data-id="map1">click here for map1<p> 
....
```

In the real script, the variable 'posts', is more complex and generates coordinates from html tables (two or more).
Someone has an idea how to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps won't work when using classes to select multiple canvases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192260/google-maps-wont-work-when-using-classes-to-select-multiple-canvases)

Comment: if you see my example (second link) I do not use the class-map to select the canvas
$('.openmap').click(function(){
varid=$(this).attr('data-id');
initialize(id);
$("#"+id).fadeIn();
});
.......
with the click step I create the unique id.

if it is another your speech then I did not understand.

Comment: Sorry. If you posted the relevant code in the question per the SO guidelines we wouldn't have wasted each others time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem starts here:

```
function Tour_startUp(stops) {
    if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
      //code
    }
}
```

It's obvious that `Tour_startUp` will do nothing when you call it the 2nd time,  because on further calls the condition `if (!window.tour)` will be false. The result: both maps will use the same `stops`-argument that has been supplied at the first call.

Rethink the design of your application, avoid global variables and use OOP.